How to verify Gmail Api token on my Server?
I have created a REST Api with Spring boot and to send emails, I have implemented the Gmail API. When I'm starting the api on my server for the first time, this comes of course :
Please open the following address in your browser:   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8888/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send

But here comes the problem. When im clicking on the link, Im gettin redirected to localhost:8888/... but as this does not runs on my computer but on the server the verification cant be executed. So my question is:
Are there any other ways to verificate? Or is there a solution for the problem?
I have tried to change the gmail.json (where the token is saved) and changed redirect_uris to the servers adress. Didnt helped.
{
    "web": {
        "client_id": "nope",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        "client_secret": "nope",
        "redirect_uris": "http://sva-doppelturnier.de:8888"
    }
}

and that is the credential funktion, whos been called to verificate the token

private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport httpTransport, GsonFactory jsonFactory)
        throws IOException {

    InputStream inputStream = MailService.class.getResourceAsStream("/gmail.json");
    if (inputStream == null) {
        logger.error("Unable to load Gmail credentials file.");
        return null;
    }
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(jsonFactory, new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientSecrets, Set.of(GMAIL_SEND))
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(Paths.get("tokens").toFile()))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();

    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
}


You need to place the file credentials.json derived from an initial authorisation where it can be loaded as a resource. Your code will need to load that explicitly

GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in)); (where in is the stream from the aforementioned resource) is what I have, admittedly for a calendar API app. I got creds for apps from the dev portal of Google

yeah. I have a gmail.json with token and all the stuff. It is getting read in row 3. Or what du you mean?

OK. If all I mentioned is in place, then there could be a different problem in your code. I've found that authentication is demanded when there is some other kind of error

may i send you more code or stuff that you can look at it and find the problem maybe?
